# Connection to SQL Server fails

Tags: sql-server, azure

I get the following error when I try to connect to my Azure SQL Server with SSMS

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 258)

I get this error when I attempt to connect with my new host provider. With my old hosting provider, I didn't have this issue. I have tried every possible solution on the internet but nothing works.

I have allowed my IP the access by adding it to the list of allowed IPs in the Azure portal. Can someone help me figure out why I can access the server with one host provider but not with the other?

Comment: Your provider certainly should have an answer.

Comment: Does your provider expose any type of connection string for accessing the server? Could they perhaps be using a port other than the default of 1433?

Comment: no the connection string uses port 1433. Connection string looks like this(ADO.NET) Server=tcp:r1x2nnsfy1.database.windows.net,1433;Database=YTProjectDb;User ID=yourtime@r1x2nnsfy1;Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must have a internet access.**
It seems that you just can't connect to the server.

**You must add your public IPv4 Address in Azure firewall list.**
Note: Some ISP will use NAT, so your public IP connect to DB may be difference from your public IP connect to Azure Portal.

Comment: Lol what do u mean switch database? I can't connect to the server in the first place.

Comment: I know how to connect to the server. That's not the issue. It has something to do with either firewall blocking my port or something else as I can't connect to the server with my new internet service provider..

Comment: Try to allow ip range 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 and then test again. After test you should delete this rule.  Some ISP will use nested NAT. It may make your public ip address different from you seen.

Comment: And you may look at `Auditing & Threat detection` in Azure Portal.

Comment: According to your error message, I think it may not be the firewall issues. Your TCP connection may not be established.   See if DNS resolved error ip address and tracert the ip address.

Comment: It's not a firewall issue as I have icluded both inbound and outbound rules for port 1433. Also I have included the rule for my ip range in azure portal. Not sure if I understand what you mean by "DNS resolved error ip address" but here's what tracet over my ip yields https://s14.postimg.io/vhpb4tgmp/Untitled.png

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with an invalid router configuration or something. I'm not an IT expert so I wouldn't know what to do.

Comment: I mean try to tracert from your computer (using new ISP) to Azure SQL (something like `example.database.windows.net`). I think it is just connection error between you and Azure SQL

Comment: Wait a moment. Your `Azure SQL Server` means `SQL Azure (a kind of SaaS)` or `SQL Server on Azure VM`. I think you means the former.

Comment: Yes I meant the former. I'm able to connect to my other Azure subscriptions but for some reason I can't connect to Azure SQL. I have been stuck on this for a long time, tried various things but to no avail. Here's the tracert from my computer to the SQL server. https://s21.postimg.io/lsqhuxr2v/Untitled.png

Comment: According to your tracert result, it's your ISP's reason that your network packet can't be route to the right destination. Since `192.168.x.x` is private ip address, your packet are just forbidden by your ISP. It may be a mistake or follow some policy.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: you may try VPN/proxy if you really has a internet access

Comment: yeah that's what I had in mid. Thanks for all your help :)